# Manage memory C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have create these simple function.

```
char* tmp = new char[len];
strncpy(tmp,str+start,len);
int ret = atoi(tmp);    
delete []tmp;
return ret;
```

I have a problem with memory managment.
When I read ret variable, the value is null. If I remove the instruction "delete []tmp;" the value is correct but the memory fast increase (because I don't release the memory).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: std::string and stringstream to convert, you are mixing C with C++

Comment: @zp26 Why? std::string can supply a `const char *` via `c_str()` (But you don't want to return that).

Comment: @zp26 Then allocate new `char[len+1]`, one more for `'\0'`

Comment: Feels like C on steroids.

Comment: A non-pointer variable can't be `NULL`. It can be zero though.

Comment: Presumably str and start are `char*`s as well?

Comment: Note that `strncpy` will corrupt your data if you pass a string that's too long. You **have to** check the value that it returns to know whether this happened.

Answer (score 1):

From man strncpy: The strncpy() function is similar than strcpy, except that at most n bytes of src are copied. Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Check your `str` variable length and verify this null terminating condicion on strncpy

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), one of them is that it doesn't have any kind of validation that the string you pass is really a number. Instead you might want to use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Also note that [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) might not terminate the string in some cases. And that you might want to allocate one extra character (`len + 1`) for the terminator.

Answer (score 1):

`strncpy` fills up the target array with '\0's once the end of the source is reached.

`atoi` expects a null terminated c-string, means an array of characters that ends with a '\0'.

Therefore you have to create an array with a size of `len + 1`, the `strncpy` function will the automatically null-terminate your target array.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have the buffer be allocated from outside the function, and pass the tmp argument as an array. A better approach though, is to allocate an object. These get destructed as long as you don't use the new keyword. `std::string` would be perfect in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `tmp` is terminated with a `'\0'`

Comment: uh, so the OP is `delete`ing his data before returning it. I think that is the least of his problems

Comment: No, the OP does not return `tmp`, but `ret`

Comment: oops. Sorry, glossed over it a bit **too** fast. I don't get the OP's post then though. How can an `int` be null?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what's wrong since `str` and `len` are not shown.

This function could be a lot simpler:

```
int ret = atoi(str + start);    
return ret;
```

BTW, `ret` is an `int` and NULL is usually referred to pointers.

Comment: Does not work because `atoi` does not know where to stop parsing the source string.

Comment: It will stop at the first char which isn't a digit, whitespace or +- sign. [See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: The problem is that you want to stop it after `len` characters at most.